# How to make normal links in TextView clickable?

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

In my Android app, I have a `TextView`. The text can contain links. This is an example of a text:

`This is just a test. Click the following link http://www.google.com to visit Google.`

Note that the text is **not in HTML**; it will be just a regular text.

I want to do something like `textView.parseLinks()`, then in the `TextView`, `http://www.google.com` will be hyper-linked and clickable to open up the page.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You say: `the text is not HTML it will be just regular text a normal person will put in.` If the user will put in text, then is this EditText or TextView ? My question is will the user put the text or it would be pre-defined ?

Comment: No there will be two activities, one where they have a multi line text edit, which gets saved to a database. The user wont know html, so they will put in text and links without html. Then on the current view, the text they put before gets downloaded and put on a textview.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try and include the following in the `TextView` definition in XML file:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:autoLink="web"/>
```

The docs of [android:autoLink](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoLink) say:

> Controls whether links such as urls and email addresses are automatically found and converted to clickable links

So for automatically finding links, the above may help. Try and see.

Comment: superb inbuilt solution ever.. thanxx man for such a important info.

Comment: ( superb.inbuilt )   if we enter words as in bracket, it also show link for those.. how can i prevent that

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work.

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String text = "This is just a test. Click this link here <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a> to visit google.";
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    <TextView
        ...
        android:autoLink="..."/>
//set  ... by web|email|none|phone|map|all according to your need
```

// to change link color add below line
android:textColorLink="@color/yourcolor"

Answer (score 2):

try this..it is working for me

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="click here http://www.google.com/"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to make selecting `URL` and Phone numbers in `TextView`:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText("some url is www.google.com phone 7504567890 another url lkgndflg.com ");
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS | Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```