# How do I get a string that contains a link in Android?

Tags: android, html, hyperlink, textview

following problem: I have got a method that generates the result of some computation and returns this result as a string. Now I would like this result to contain a clickable link. How do I do that?

Here is what I have done so far:

This is part of my method that generates the result string:

```
Spanned link = Html.fromHtml("<a href='http://www.apple.com'>Apple.com</a>");
String result = "Website is: " + link;
```

Then, in another method that uses the String `result` I just set the text of the TextView `resultText` like this:

```
resultText.setText(result);
```

The problem is that while the text is displayed the text is not a link and hence not clickable. However, I already set this attribute in XML file of the according TextView:

```
android:linksClickable="true"
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Try to add this android:autoLink="all" and this android:autoLink="web"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself with the help of this post on http://android-coding.blogspot.de/2013/04/display-html-string-with-link-on.html

Here is what I did, maybe it is helpful to someone in the future:

I made these changes (compare with them with my code in my question)

1. In my result String generating method I put this code:

   ```
   String link = "<a href='http://www.apple.com'>Apple.com</a>";
   String result = "Website is: " + link;
   ```
2. **Remove** these attributes from the XML in your TextView

   ```
   android:autoLink="web"
   android:linksClickable="true"
   ```
3. When you actually set the text in your textview, do it like this:

   ```
   resultText.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
   resultText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

See [How to make normal links in TextView clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222433/how-to-make-links-in-textview-clickable-in-android/18222583#18222583) question.

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:autoLink="web"/>
```

`android:autoLink="web"` controls whether links such as urls and email addresses are automatically found and converted to clickable links in `TextView`. Try and see.

**Update**:

In your original code try

```
Spanned link = Html.fromHtml("![CDATA[<a href="http://www.apple.com">Apple.com</a>]]");
```

**or**

declare a string in string.xml:

```
<string name="mylinks"><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.apple.com">Apple.com</a>]]></string>
```

and then

```
String link = Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.mylinks));
```

Comment: Don't use HTML. Try something like this: `String result = "Website is: " + "http://www.apple.com ";`

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to display the URL. I just want the clickable text that is inside the HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut the string according to ' . You can do this trim() or substring() method.Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) link.