# Add domain to a relative link

Tags: java, android, html

I'm fetching some data containing HTML from my server to use in my app, and the html has some links like `<a href="/go/here">Go here</a>`.

I'm applying the html to a TextView like

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

The link works, but causes my app to crash with

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/go/here...`
```

I'm guessing the crash is because it's a relative link and doesn't have the domain in. Is there any methods, maybe Regex, to search for all `<a/>` tags and add the domain before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to go the simplest way:

```
final String faultyHtml = "Link: <a href=\"/images/nav_logo193.png\">click here</a> etc etc";
final String domain = "http://www.google.fr";

final String fixedHtml = faultyHtml.replace("href=\"/", "href=\"" + domain + "/");

text.setText(Html.fromHtml(fixedHtml));
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

(all occurrences would be added the same domain though)

Comment: I forgot to put in my post, they will all be to the same domain, so this is perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = htmlString.indexOf("<a>");
String part1 = htmlString.subString(0,index+2);
String part2 = htmlString.subString(index+3);
String newHtmlString = part1+"http://"+part2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this codes.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String text = "This is just a test. Click this link here <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a> to visit google.";
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

reference [How to make links in textview clickable in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222433/how-to-make-links-in-textview-clickable-in-android)